# time formatting in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, format

I have time series per minute that look as shown below. The format is like '"hh:mm"' as seen below

'"8:59"'
    '"9:00"'
    '"9:01"'
    '"9:02"'
    '"9:03"'
    '"9:04"'
    '"9:05"'
    '"9:06"'
    '"9:07"'

Is it possible to change these to hhmm format in matlab like 859 900 901 902 t0 a double format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function like [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) or [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to get rid of the colon in the string. For example:

```
t = {'"8:59"', '"9:00"', '"9:01"', '"9:02"'};
newt = strrep(t, ':', '');
newt = strrep(newt, '"', '');
newt = strrep(newt, ''', '');
```

Or the slightly bizarre `regexprep` call:

```
newt = regexprep(t, '[''''"'':]', '');
```

Returns

```
newt = 

    '859'    '900'    '901'    '902'
```

Which you can then use with `str2double` to generate your vector of doubles:

```
tdouble = str2double(newt);
```

Which returns:

```
tdouble =

   859   900   901   902
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html), which are the MATLAB builtins for manipulating serial date values. For example:

```
tother = datenum(t, 'HH:MM');
```

Returns:

```
tother =

   1.0e+05 *

    7.3597
    7.3597
    7.3597
    7.3597
```

And to go back:

```
totherstr = datestr(tother, 'HH:MM');
```

Which returns:

```
totherstr =

08:59
09:00
09:01
09:02
```

Comment: strrep works quite well and is returning a vector of time stamps of type cell, however string to double is returning a NAN all through the vector, any suggestion? thx

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the data you provided. I've updated my answer to also remove the unnecessary quotation marks. It's not the prettiest but it accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 0):

To string

```
 strjoin(strsplit(s, ':'),'')
```

to double

```
 str2num(strjoin(strsplit(s, ':'),''))
```

If you have those quotes `""` and want to remove them, then use this here

```
 str2num(strjoin(strsplit(s(3:end-2), ':'),''))
```